# Can I disable remmina applet from startup applications

Tags: boot, startup

I actually am a new person to Ubuntu and I don't have that fast system so where is remmina applet used and is it safe for me to disable it as a startup application I use 20.04

Answer (score 2):

[here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Remmina#:%7E:text=Remmina%20is%20the%20default%20remote,%2C%20NX%2C%20XDMCP%20and%20SSH.) you see what is *Remmina applet*.

It is used for remote desktop communication, So if you are a normal user you can remove it.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir